# Convert Nancy ModelValidationResult To IDictionary<string, string>

Tags: validation, nancy

I am trying to convert a Nancy ModelValidationResult into IDictionary where they key is the field and the value is the error messages.

I have this working as a bunch of loops, I want to know if there is a simpler way of doing this?

Here is my code snippet.

```
var result =  this.Validate(model);

                if (!result.IsValid)
                {
                    foreach(var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        foreach(var key in error.MemberNames)
                        {
                            if(model.Errors.Keys.Contains(key))
                            {
                                model.Errors[key] = string.Format("{0} {1}", model.Errors[key], error.GetMessage(key));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                model.Errors.Add(key, error.GetMessage(key));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return View["enter-details", model];
                }
```

Comment: you could rewrite to linq, if you consider that simpler

Comment: The next release (0.22) will contain a huge overhaul of model validationhttps://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1265 where we changes how the information is sent back. More specifically https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1318